# How to add custom component inside an Flatlist in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Flatlist on react native by which its working perfectly, recently saw an UI which has a custom designed compoenent in between the list, kindly check the below reference image

Check this image, a new design named "Safety+" has been added inside an list, How to do this ?

Need to add custom design like below randomly inside and already rendered flatlist ! How to achieve this , as i couldn't find or understand where to start

[image]

Please check the image and help in achieving this:

```
 <FlatList 
                    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}
                    data={this.state.availableBusList}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                        return(
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.busCardContainer}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        console.log(item);
                                        //this.props.navigation.navigate('SeatLayout')
                                    }}

                                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                                >)}}
/>
```

This is my flatlist code

Comment: Do you want a custom component separating *each* item? or only "randomly" include it? What have you tried? Please be more specific with what your desired output should/could be.

Comment: Randomly include it . I dont know where to start, as the flatlist renders a list - i dont know how to intrude it and add a custom component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a fragment with your component and a randomly included component. The condition for inclusion is up to you, i.e. complete chance, every 5th element, etc.

```
<FlatList 
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}
  data={this.state.availableBusList}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    return(
      <Fragment> 
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.busCardContainer}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log(item);
            //this.props.navigation.navigate('SeatLayout')
          }}
        >
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {Math.random() < 0.5 && ( // example 50% chance to include random component
          <RandomComponent>...</RandomComponent>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    )}}
/>
```

Comment: Can Fragment be used on React Native ?

Comment: @letmethink02 It appears `<>` and `</>` are, and these are shorthand JSX for `<Fragment>` and </Fragment>` so I'm inclined to say, yes, I think they can be used in RN... and just confirmed `Fragment` does indeed work in an expo [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/fragment-test). AFAIK, anything `React` works in react-native (versions accepting, OFC).

Comment: thanks working, as we can combine both Fragments and Index as mentioned by @Thanh Chương it works

Comment: @letmethink02 Yup, absolutely. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You can render conditionally in your renderItem function: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Additionally, if you want to render your custom component at specific indexes, you can also put index parameter into renderItem. Here is my example:

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}
  data={this.state.availableBusList}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
    return index % 5 === 0 ? <CustomComponent /> : <NormalComponent />;
  }}
/>
```

Comment: What if OP wants to also display every 5th element of their data?

Comment: The CustomComponent can be like this: const CustomComponent = props => <>{...content}<NormalComponent /></>
This is similar to @DrewReese's way in another answer. I just want to give more way so that OP can more easily figured the solution.

Comment: It works on both your approach and fragments ! thanks